# Using Fish Shell, how can I export a variable from within a file?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

We can export variables from the command line with `set -x`, but I'd like to know how to do this from within a file. The reason is that I'm organizing my $HOME directory according to the XDG convention, and the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory) says this about **zsh**:

> Consider exporting `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh` in `~/.zshenv`. You could also add this to `/etc/zsh/zshenv`.

I want to effect an export from `/etc/zsh/zshenv` to avoid cluttering my $HOME. Can I simply input the Fish Shell command `set -x` from within this file or is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: why would the fish shell read your /etc/zsh/zshenv? fish is not zsh!

Comment: I want to prevent the dot file from being created in my home directory. I don't have zsh, but Cargo is creating `~/.zshenv`. I was hoping to prevent that.

Comment: what does Cargo have to do with fish? and what with zsh?  Really confused now!

Comment: Fish is my shell. So I use it to manage my system's environment variables. If I'm told to modify an environment variable, then I think to use my shell to do that.

Comment: yes, but what does setting environment variables in your shell have to do with Cargo creating dotfiles? And where does zsh come into play here? I'm simply not getting the bigger picture, sorry!

Comment: I don't know why or how Cargo interfaces with zsh. But it does. And I just want to clean my $HOME.

Comment: so, how do environment variables come into play here? I'm really really confused.

Comment: The Arch wiki explains how to organize one's files according to XDG. I pasted what they said in my OP.

Comment: Environment variables are used all over the Arch wiki on XDG.

Comment: Sorry, all these things aren't connected in a meaningful way. Just things using environment variables doesn't have anything to do with cargo creating some files in your home directory. And fish has absolutely nothing to do with this at all, it seems!

Comment: When I'm told to change my environment variables, I always use Fish because Fish is my shell. The Arch wiki says to change my environment variables. When it says to do that from the command line, I can do it. For example, I did that with Go, Less, Git, and many others. None of those are Fish, but I used Fish to change the environment variables. Now I want to do that for zsh.

Comment: I must really be missing something. Could you **edit** your question to explain your full motivation, starting from what you're doing, what causes cargo to create some files you can't have (and why you can't have them), to what environment variables you want to export for which purpose. This all so far has made zero sense to me :(

Answer (score 4):

Have you read about fish's config files? [Configuration files](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#configuration-files)

If you want to set up an environment variable for Cargo, you can:

- create a universal variable once: `set -Ux VARIABLE=value`
- add an entry into `$HOME/.config/fish/config.fish`: `set -gx VARIABLE=VALUE`
- create a file in `$HOME/.config/fish/conf.d/`, say `cargo.fish` that contains that `set -gx` line.

I would avoid adding app-specific env.vars into "global" rc files (e.g. /etc/fish/config.fish) -- keep your own settings in your own configuration files.